# Addition columns codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How i can addtion all columns of a table (tablename cashbox) with codeignitter? I have this code and this table.

sql:

```
cash_id incoming outgoing

   1     215.55   55.22

   2     58.69    4.88

   3      100      20
```

Now i need a total from incoming 374.24 and outgoing 80,1 but i dont work for me.

```
$data['cashbox'] = $this->db->query('SELECT SUM(incoming) FROM cashbox')->num_rows();
```

view `<?= $cashbox ?>`

Comment: Why are you using `num_rows` if you want total. use `result` and change `$data['cashbox'] = $this->db->select_sum('incoming')->result();`. it will return `array` so `$data['cashbox'][0]`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But i get this with this code "Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()"

Comment: you have use `$this->db->get();` too. `$query = $this->db->select_sum('incoming', 'incoming');
$query = $this->db->get('cashbox');
$result = $query->result();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change statement like this:

```
$this->db->select_sum('incoming','incoming');
$this->db->from('cashbox');
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['cashbox'] = $query->row()->incoming;
```

Comment: But now i have the problem with the 
decimal place . If i add some numbers like 0.15, 3.73, 25, 28.80 i get this fback 57.67999999999999 . How i can make that i get only xx.xx

Answer (score 1):

This code should help you.

```
$query = $this->db->select_sum('incoming', 'incoming');
$query = $this->db->get('cashbox');
$result = $query->result();
echo return $result[0]->incoming;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in your model. I think it works.

```
$this->db->select_sum('incoming');
$this->db->from('your table name')
$query = $this->db->get();   
return $query->$result[0]->incoming;
```